# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Board & Card Games breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1          6
Users destroyed                                   7          0
Users contacted                                   4          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            17      1,186
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                1        270
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          3        792
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        327
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 8      1,114
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                5        971
Tags merged                                      32          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            32          0
Tag synonyms created                             33          0
Questions reopened                               13         25
Questions protected                               0         45
Questions flagged⁴                                2        163
Questions closed                                 16        298
Question flags handled⁴                          89         76
Posts undeleted                                   4         16
Posts locked                                      0         30
Posts deleted⁵                                   73        470
Posts bumped                                      0        148
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  1        421
Comments deleted⁶                               471        849
Comment flags handled                           277        145
Answers flagged                                   4        770
Answer flags handled                            217        557
All comments on a post moved to chat              6          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 2):

I am glad the site is still alive. And I think there is a slight increase in activity. But we have still a long way to go. So keep on gaming.